# Prove that ((∩))/ is a subgroup of /. Then, Deduce ((∩))/ is Abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that ,, are subgroups of ,  is a normal subgroup of . Assume / is Abelian. Prove that ((∩))/ is a subgroup of /. Then, Deduce ((∩))/ is Abelian.

I can prove (∩) is a subgroup of . However, I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: What's with the boxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**  Use the canonical projection:  $\pi:G\to G/H$ by $\pi (x)=xH$, where $H\trianglelefteq G$.

Also, the facts that a normal subgroup is also normal in any subgroup (that contains it).  And, of course,  any subgroup of an abelian group is abelian.